# sp_xml_preparedocument

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

How to process xml string into store procedure? any help?
I don't find sp_xml_preparedocument procedure in sql server 2008...

Any input?

Answer (score 0):

Use XML methods with XPath. See [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx):

- [query()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx)
- [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)
- [exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx)
- [modify()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx)
- [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)